# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid superclass index 0 in class file com/github/javaparser/JavaParser

Tags: java

I am pretty new for java.I am trying to make a project that get class names,field names from desired .java file with [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser).
But I get an error and i don't know anything about this error.How can fix that error?

1-)First I create a new project on NetBeans IDE

2-) Add JavaParser dependency pom.xml file and "mvn clean install" on project folder.(Probabably I am do this wrong)

3-)Create files and type following codes

4-)Compile and i get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid superclass index 0 in class file com/github/javaparser/JavaParser
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at parser.GetTypes.parseClassname(GetTypes.java:28)
    at parser.Parser.main(Parser.java:28)
C:\Users\q\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Parser.java File(src/parser/Parser.java):

```
package parser;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Parser {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  { 
   System.out.println(GetTypes.parseClassname(new File("C:\\HelloOOPP.java")));
    }
  }
```

GetTypes.java File(src/parser/GetTypes.java):

```
package parser;
import com.github.javaparser.*;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.*;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.*;
import com.github.javaparser.symbolsolver.model.declarations.TypeDeclaration;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class GetTypes {
    public static String parseClassname(File filename) throws FileNotFoundException   {

            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
            CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(fin);
           // String packagePrefix = cu.getPackage().getName().toString();
            //if (!packagePrefix.isEmpty()) packagePrefix += ".";
            StringBuilder build=new  StringBuilder();
            for (TypeDeclaration type : cu.getTypes())
            {
                if (type.isClass())
                { 
                    build.append("Class Name:");
                    build.append(type.getName());
                    build.append("\n");
                    build.append("Fields");
                    //build.append(Get_Fields(type));
                }                   
            }
            return build.toString();      
    }   
     private String Get_Fields(TypeDeclaration c) //
     {
         Field[] fields = c.getClass().getFields();
         StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
         for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
         {
             str.append(fields[i].getName());
             str.append("\n");
         }
         return str.toString();
     }
     /*
     private int Count_Fields(TypeDeclaration c)
     {   
     }*/

}
```

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- This is often your domain name (reversed.)  -->
    <groupId>com.parser</groupId>
    <!-- The name of this project (actually, the name of the artifact, which is the thing that this project produces. A jar in this case.) -->
    <artifactId>parser</artifactId>
    <!-- The version of this project. SNAPSHOT means "we're still working on it" -->
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- Tell Maven we want to use Java 8 -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- Tell Maven to treat all source files as UTF-8 -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Here are all your dependencies. Currently only one. These are automatically downloaded from https://mvnrepository.com/ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaparser-symbol-solver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

mvn clean install on cmd:

```
C:\parser>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building parser 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ parser ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\parser\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ parser ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\parser\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ parser ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ parser ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\parser\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ parser ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ parser ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ parser ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: C:\parser\target\parser-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ parser ---
[INFO] Installing C:\parser\target\parser-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\q\.m2\repository\com\parser\parser\1.0-SNAPSHOT\parser-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\parser\pom.xml to C:\Users\q\.m2\repository\com\parser\parser\1.0-SNAPSHOT\parser-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.193 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-08T16:41:28+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You are adding the wrong dependency to your project. According to the documentation of the project you are using you should use javaparser-symbol-solver-core and you are using javaparser-core. **ALWAYS** read the documentation. Don't rely on examples they usually are outdated.

Comment: https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser section maven.

Comment: I change javaparser-core to javaparser-symbol-solver-core and run "mvn clean install" on cmd and it downloads some packages and finish.After that I try to compile on NetBeans and i get same error.

Comment: You gona need to download their source and debug it to see what it is wrong. It may be their problem then.

Comment: Also, add your pom file here in your question. Don't link it to external temporary sources, as it is temporary eventually this link will cease to exist and it will not help others in future.

Comment: Also there is another section in the docs that states: *If you checkout the sources and want to view the project in an IDE, it is best to first generate some of the source files; otherwise you will get many compilation complaints in the IDE. (mvn clean install already does this for you.)* Have you done that? "mvn javacc:javacc"

Comment: Yes,i add the "mvn clean install" results at the end of the question.

Comment: Everything seems fine then, download their source and debug it on your IDE.

Comment: After changed javaparser-core to javaparser-symbol-solver-core it get following error:com.github.javaparser.ast.body does not exist and other errors gone.

Comment: Take a look here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javaparser . It seems that they separated the modules so it is possible that that missing library is in one of the others. What I would do is to add all other dependencies test it and if it works I would start to remove and test to keep only the needed ones.

Answer (score 1):

**Invalid superclass index 0 in class file**. In my case it is resolved by deleting the the NetBeans Cache Folder.

```
C:\....\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache
```

Comment: It was also solved by cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

My fault.The problem is "used netbeans structure on my project and tried to add packages with maven".I create a new file and create a file structure follow this tutorial :[maven file structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)
 implement my code for this structure and everythings work fine